# How can I change asciidoc code block style by using notepad++ regular expressions?

Tags: notepad++, asciidoc

I am trying to change HTML asciidoc code blocks like. I want to c convert specific code block style using notepad++ regular expressions.
Every code block starts with a new line

**Default Form**

```
....
>>> def echo(value=None):
 print("Execution starts when 'next()' is called for the first time.")
 try:
     while True:
         try:
             value = (yield value)
         except Exception as e:
....
```

**Desired Form:**

```
[source,python]
----
    >>> def echo(value=None):
     print("Execution starts when 'next()' is called for the first time.")
     try:
         while True:
             try:
                 value = (yield value)
             except Exception as e:
----
```

I am using the following regular expressions in order but they didn't work.

1.
From :`\r\n....`
To :`\r\n[source,python]\r\n----`

2.
From :`....`
To :`----`

Comment: I think this will be very hard to do using only Notepad++ regex.  Do you have access to a Python IDE?  It might be fairly easy to do this formatting there.  In general, this is really a job for a parser, rather than a single regex.

Comment: Thanks. How can I do this with by using the parser?

Comment: To write a parser from scratch would be a bunch of code.  If you have a good Python IDE available, it should already have tools for doing some/all of the formatting changes you want.

Comment: Yes. I have Python and Java IDE. I have knowledge of these languages. Any guide or documentation about parsing can be helpful

Comment: There are no hyphen (`-`) characters in your "Default form" and so the "From" string cannot match. Please [edit] the question to make it clear what you have tried, what happened, what was correct and what failed. The part of your question saying *"but some didn't like this"* does not explain what was wrong with the text that follows.

Comment: Ahh thanks write wrong there.I have edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that the `.` is a special character in regular expressions. To match a literal `.` you need to escape it `\.`.

You can use the following expression. Make sure that the *Regular expressions*, *matches newline*, *match case* and *wrap around* options are enabled.

**Find what**:

```
(\.\.\.\.)\s(.*?)(\.\.\.)
```

**Replacing with**:

```
[source,python]\n----\2----
```

---

After replacement:

```
[source,python]
----
>>> def echo(value=None):
 print("Execution starts when 'next()' is called for the first time.")
 try:
     while True:
         try:
             value = (yield value)
         except Exception as e:
----
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it, It works like a charm but When I tried it my python documentation which has 141 code block, some code blocks is are processed wrong 

For example:

`....
class Philosopher:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, default_name, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
....
`

is converted to 

`
class Philosopher:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, default_name, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
[source,python]
----
`

I converted  [from](https://anotepad.com/notes/fy8ky2) [to](https://anotepad.com/notes/eqdts2)

Comment: A bit hard to see it from the comment/link you shared. Can you add the code block for which it does not work to the OP post?

Comment: [Code does not work](https://anotepad.com/notes/f9xj9e) 
[Full Documentation Before Conversion](https://anotepad.com/notes/fy8ky2) 
[Full Documentation After Conversion](https://anotepad.com/notes/eqdts2)

Comment: Right, to clarify, should that block of code be changed as the other block code in the OP or should be left intact?

Comment: This regex seems to change the code block like this: `[source,python]----code----` But it can't.Strangely it converted like this `code[source,python]----`.

Comment: I tested it on Notepad++ and the "code that does not work" is converted fine.  Granted there is a `trailing dot` because of five `-`. What version of Notepad++ are you using? Again, it would be useful if you added this information to the OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178253/discussion-between-my-lord-and-unbearablelightness).